# VUE undefined error after splice the last element

Tags: arrays, vue.js, undefined, splice

This is simplified version of bigger component I'm working on. Please help me to solve the mystery - why I'm getting error on deleting (splicing) the last item from the list ?

- If you delete one by one - no error. It happens, only when the last item is deleted and at least one item is in front of it.
- If  `@click="handleProductLineTap(line, index)"`  is removed at v-for - no error.

```
    <template>
      <div v-for="(row, index) in this.rows" :key="index" v-bind:id="`row-${index}`"  @click="handleProductrowTap(index)">
        <div v-bind:id="`row-${index}`" v-bind:class="rowCssDecorations(row, index)">
          <span>{{ row.text }}</span> <button class="borderNormal" style="background-color: white; border:black;" @click.prevent="deleteRow(row, index)">Delete me </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'TestRow',
      created() {},
      data() {
        return {
          rows: [
            {'id':1, text: 'Granny smith', type: 'apple'},
            {'id':2, text: 'Conference', type: 'pear'},
            {'id':3, text: 'Alpine', type: 'strawberry'},
          ],
          currentRowIndex: 0
        }
      },
      methods: {
        //returns css styling to every row in v-for. 
        //It sets color of the row according to the row.type and highlights selected row (if currentRowIndex == index). 
        rowCssDecorations(row) {
          var resultingCss = ''
    
          //change color according to rows.type
          switch (row.type) {
            case 'apple':
              resultingCss = resultingCss + 'appleClass'
              break
            case 'pear':
              resultingCss = resultingCss + 'pearClass'
              break
            case 'strawberry':
              resultingCss = resultingCss + 'strawberryClass'
              break
    
            default:
              resultingCss = resultingCss + 'defaultClass'
              break
          }
    
          //Hliglight the current row
          if (this.rows[this.currentRowIndex].id == row.id) {
            resultingCss = resultingCss + ' borderSelected '
            } else {
              resultingCss = resultingCss + ' borderNormal  '
            }
    
          return resultingCss
        },
    
        //deletes the row
        deleteRow(index) {
          this.rows.splice(index, 1)
        },
    
        //Simply sets the selected row id to currentRowIndex  .
        handleProductrowTap( index) {
          this.currentRowIndex = index
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
    <style lang="scss" scoped>
    .appleClass {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }
    .pearClass {
      background-color: palegoldenrod;
    }
    .strawberryClass {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .defaultClass {
      background-color: gainsboro;
    }
    .borderSelected{
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 4px;
    }
    .borderNormal{
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 2px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue as i am not getting any error. here is the working jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/L02ukqbw/

Comment: Try this complete version https://jsfiddle.net/5rfy8L1b/
If you click to delete the last row, you will get 

<a class='gotoLine' href='#"[Vue warn'>"[Vue warn</a>: Error in render function: 
(found in &lt;Root&gt;)"]
<a class='gotoLine' href='#[object Error] { ... }'>[object Error] { ... }</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the fiddle link you shared, I came up with below observations/root cause **:**

- You are calling `deleteRow` method with two parameters (row, index) but in the method definition you are accepting only `index` which causing the issue in delete the record.

  To resolve this you have to just pass the index in `deleteRow` method from the template.
- Another observation is that as you are passing `row` and `index` both in `rowCssDecorations` method. Hence, no need of `currentRowIndex`, you can directly use the `index` in `rowCssDecorations` method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [{
        'id': 1,
        text: 'Granny smith',
        type: 'apple'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        text: 'Conference',
        type: 'pear'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        text: 'Alpine',
        type: 'strawberry'
      }
    ],
    currentRowIndex: 0
  },
  methods: {
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.rows.splice(index, 1)
    },
    
    rowCssDecorations(row, index) {
      var resultingCss = ''

      //change color according to rows.type
      switch (row.type) {
        case 'apple':
          resultingCss = resultingCss + 'appleClass'
          break
        case 'pear':
          resultingCss = resultingCss + 'pearClass'
          break
        case 'strawberry':
          resultingCss = resultingCss + 'strawberryClass'
          break

        default:
          resultingCss = resultingCss + 'defaultClass'
          break
      }

      //Hliglight the current row
      if (this.rows[index].id == row.id) {
        resultingCss = resultingCss + ' borderSelected '
      } else {
        resultingCss = resultingCss + ' borderNormal  '
      }

      return resultingCss
    },

    //deletes the row
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.rows.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
 .appleClass {
   background-color: greenyellow;
 }

 .pearClass {
   background-color: palegoldenrod;
 }

 .strawberryClass {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .defaultClass {
   background-color: gainsboro;
 }

 .borderSelected {
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 4px;
 }

 .borderNormal {
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(row, index) in this.rows" :key="index" v-bind:id="`row-${index}`">
    <div v-bind:id="`row-${index}`" v-bind:class="rowCssDecorations(row, index)">
      <span>{{ row.text }}</span> <button class="borderNormal" @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)">Delete me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@click.stop` instead of `@click.prevent`

Comment: Thanks a lot for idea! Unfortunately error still there with @click.stop

Comment: IF you click on the first row from the stacktrace in the browser's console - where does it take you? Which line in the source code?

Comment: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" - it leads to here 

if (this.rows[this.currentRowIndex].id == row.id) {

Comment: Well, then simply add a conditional chaining operator like `if (this.rows[this.currentRowIndex]?.id == row.id)` or the old-school way `if ((this.rows[this.currentRowIndex] || {}).id == row.id)` and don't forget to add `if (this.currentRowIndex >= this.rows.length) this.currentRowIndex = this.rows.length - 1;` to the `deleteRow()` function.